# generate variable names in for loop

Tags: r

Hope you don't mind if this is too easy for you.

In R, I am using fromJSON() to read from 3 urls (tier 1 url) , in the JSON file there is "link" field which give me another url (tier 2 url) and I use that and read.table() to get my final data.  My code now is like this:

```
# note, this code does not run
urlJohn <- www.foo1.com
urlJane <- www.foo2.com
urlJoe <- www.foo3.com

tempJohn <- fromJson(urlJohn)
tempJohn[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>%
   {clean up this data}
dataJohn <- read.table(tempJohn[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,
                       header = TRUE,
                       sep = ",")

tempJane <- fromJson(urlJane)
tempJane[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>%
   {clean up this data}
dataJane <- read.table(tempJane[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,
                       header = TRUE,
                       sep = ",")

tempJoe <- fromJson(urlJoe)
tempJoe[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>%
   {clean up this data}
dataJoe <- read.table(tempJoe[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,
                       header = TRUE,
                       sep = ",")
```

As you can see, I am just copying-n-pasting code blocks.  What I wish is this:

```
# note, this code also does not run
urlJohn <- www.foo1.com
urlJane <- www.foo2.com
urlJoe <- www.foo3.com
source <- c("John", "Jane", "joe")

for (i in source){
   temp <- paste(temp, i, sep = "")
   url <- paste(url, i, sep = "")
   data <- paste(data, i, sep = "")
   temp <- fromJson(url)
      temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>%
         {clean up this data}
      data <- read.table(temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,
                         header = TRUE,
                         sep = ",")
}
```

What do I need to do to make the for loop work?  If my question is not clear, please ask me to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find using `lapply` convenient than a `for` loop. Although you can easily convert this to a for loop if needed.

```
URLs <- c('www.foo1.com', 'www.foo2.com', 'www.foo3.com')

lapply(URLs, function(x)  {
  temp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x)
  temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>% {clean up this data}
  read.table(temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,header = TRUE,sep = ",")
}) -> list_data

list_data
```

Comment: thanks!  Can this method also save the intermediate value, the "temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link" (the cleaned up version)?

Comment: I think `temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>% {clean up this data}` is already cleaning and saving it, right?

Comment: I tried.  The intermediate value is not saved.  It lives in the function only.

Comment: `%<>%` saves the data back to it's origin which can be verified with this example `df<- data.frame(a = 1:5)` and then do `df[['a']] %<>% sqrt` or `df$a %<>% sqrt`. Both of them work. So if it is not working for you it really depends on what you are doing in `{clean up this data}` part or somewhere else. Unfortunately, since you have not shared any data nor have you shared any details of `{clean up this data}` I cannot check why it is not working for you.

Comment: But, it did not work here: `x <- list(a = 1:10, beta = exp(-3:3), logic = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))`
`lapply(x, function(x){
  temp <- x
  temp %<>% sum(x)
  temp / 2
})`
`temp`

Comment: I don't see how this is related to your actual question. If it is confusing, I would suggest use the simple `<-` operator. `temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link <- temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %>% do something`

Comment: The `temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>% {clean up this data}` is an intermediate value in the function.  When `lapply` complete its work, the intermediate value disappears as well.   Maybe I need to use `lapply` twice, one for the intermediate value, one for the final value.

Comment: The final output of `{clean up this data}` should be a cleaned string which can be used to replace `temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link` value.

Comment: The `read.table` is the final output of `lapply`.  The `{clean up this data}` is gone once `lapply` completes its work.  Maybe I am not grasping your whole meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ronak Shah.  The R community strongly favors "non-For-loop" solution.

The way to get my desired result is `lapply`.

Below is non-running codes in mnemonics:

```
URLs <- c('www.foo1.com', 'www.foo2.com', 'www.foo3.com')

lapply(URLs, function(x)  {
  temp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x)
  x <- temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link %<>% {clean up this data}
  y <- read.table(temp[["data"]][["rows"]]$link,header = TRUE,sep = ",")
  return(list(x, y))
})
```

And this is a running example.

```
x <- list(alpha = 1:10, 
          beta = exp(-3:3), 
          logic = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)) 

lapply(x, function(x){
  temp <- sum(x) / 2
  temp2 <- list(x,
                temp)
  return(temp2)
  }
)
```